# The operation timed out – ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a vanilla ASP app that runs on IIS 5.1. The below code in an ASP file causes the IIS throw the “Operation timed out” error. However despite of the error the process continues to run on the server at the background and eventually completes as expected.

I increased the ASP Script timeout in  IIS via both IIS MMC and the ASP file (Server.ScriptTimeout) from 90 seconds (default) to 600, 1000 and even 10000 seconds (I know the implications of very high script timeouts) but the error occurred consistently regardless of the scrip timeout set.

WebServ is a COM+ app and I observed that the process that runs inside the app takes about 80 - 90 seconds. This app does not manipulate any IIS settings internally.

Although the code in the COM+ app could be optimized, I doubt that the optimizations alone will help because the application deals with large amount of data stored in SQL Server. Hence chances are high that the app will need more than 90 seconds to complete the process as the databases grow.

Therefore can somebody please help me understand 
1. Why the error “Operation timed out” occurs regardless of the ASP Script timeout set?
2. What should we do to buy more time for the ASP file to complete the process?

P.S. I did browse a number of other posts here related to this error message but unfortunately did not find anything helpful.

Thanks.

```
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout = 10000

.... initialize the variables....

Set WebServ = CreateObject("WebServ.RunCommand")

lcResult = WebServ.Call(SessionKey, ConfigID, Program, Function, Mode, Params)

Set WebServ = Nothing

With Response
    .ContentType = "text/xml"
    .Write(lcResult)
End With
%>
```

Comment: btw. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  -> The timeout will not take effect while a server component is processing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to increase time out in Attached application pool of the application.

Comment: Thanks. But this is IIS 5.1. Does it support app pools? I have already mentioned that increasing the ASP timeout via the MMC and ASP page doesnt make a difference unless of course if I do something differently next time.

Answer (score 0):

What should the contents of lcResult be?

Place several response.write and response.end in your code to try to find where the timeout is happening.

Comment: Sorry, above is not clear. Can you please advise where I should place multiple Response.Write and Response.End statements in the above ASP file? As to the contents of lcResult, it contains few rows from a very small table in XML format.

Comment: I'm certain that the timeout occurs while running the line lcResult = WebServ.Call(SessionKey, ConfigID, Program, Function, Mode, Params). But the actual time taken to complete this line doesnt even get closer to the ScriptTimeout set at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add Output Debug Strings to the COM Modules.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

you can view them with your debugger or DebugView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

aswell i would wrap output debug string as a COM Module to use it from ASP.

Comment: As mentioned in one of my comments below, I have isolated the method in the COM app within which the timeout fires. This method attempts to insert large number (~4K) of rows to a SQL Server table within a loop, but the entire COM process completes well under 90 seconds which is very less comparing to the ScriptTimeOut set at the beginning of the script. Still Operation timeout fires. Any reason you can think of? For instance do loops with fairly large iterations prone to this type of errors? Loop in the COM app is not an infinite loop.

Comment: does this happen if you work alone on the server or is there always traffic? anyway, inserting 4k of rows should never take 90 seconds. i think it could be a ado command / connection timeout inside the com object. what says the sql profiler while you get the asp error?